# How can I apply a tab leader indentation/nesting style in Microsoft PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, presentations

I am doing a presentation and I need to customise my bullet points so they are indented in the following manner:

```
heading 1
....heading 2
....heading 3
.........heading 4
heading 6
....heading 7
.........heading 8
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

After you enter a bullet, hit enter to start a new bullet.  Once you have done this, you can use `TAB` to *increase* the bullet's nesting level, or `SHIFT + TAB` to *decrease* the nesting level.  You can use this technique in Microsoft Word as well.

Similarily, under the **Home** tab, there are two discrete buttons to both increase and decrease the current indentation levels, which perform the same actions as TAB or SHIFT+TAB.

Comment: yeah but I want something with not just bullet points but with ....

Comment: @dublintech So you want the whitespace to be replaced with period characters.  I apologize, I misinterpreted your question; you might want to edit it to reflect what you actually want here.